# Why export command works that way?

Tags: linux, bash, shell

I have found something interesting about "export" command.

Assume, we have server Main and server Secondary. We are on Main server. Where is a script.sh on Secondary server, that has following content:

```
#!/bin/bash
echo $CI
```

Our goal is to pass env variables from Main to Secondary via ssh.

If we use command:
`export CI="CD" && ssh Secondary "echo $CI > file ; cat file ; export CI=$CI;  rm -f file ; ./script.sh"`
output will be:

```
CD
CD
```

But if we use command:
`export CI="CD" && ssh Secondary "echo $CI > file ; cat file ; export CI;  rm -f file ; ./script.sh"`
output will be:

```
CD
```

Why does it work this way? Why ./script.sh doesn't get variable $CI in second example?  May be where is any depth of export command?

Comment: In the second command, you just write `export CI`, so the variable exists and placed into the envionment, but does not get a value. Therefore script.sh prints an empty line..

Answer (score 1):

In the first case, you're using double quotes. Variables are expanded in double quotes on the Main server, so the command that the Secondary sees is in fact

```
echo CD > file ; cat file ; export CI=CD;  rm -f file ; ./script.sh
```

In the second case, there's only one instance of a variable to expand in the command.

Answer (score 0):

Before any execution, shells substitute (expand) variables.

In the first command you create (on Secondary) an environment variable called CI with the value of the one provided from Main: `export CI=$CI`.
The command `export CI=$CI` is executed on Secondary but the variable `$CI` is expanded on Main before the command is launched (the shell on Main expands the variables). The substitution gives `export CI=CD`, exactly as it would have been typed like this.

In the second, you create an empty environment variable (`export CI`).